# MySQL Stored Procedure returns wrong value only first time of execution

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

My stored procedure counts totals. If I define and save it as a new procedure and run it it returns a wrong value for only one row. If I then run it again it returns the correct value. When I call it from php it always returns the wrong value. Also this error only occurs on my server (mysql 5.5.43), on my local pc with wamp and mysql 5.5.24 it runs correct always.

I think the error must be in the following piece of the procedure:

```
create temporary table tmp2 engine=memory 
SELECT
*,
@i := @i + 1 AS teller,
@sum := if(@id = id AND @projectId = project_id,@sum,0) + aantal AS totaal,
@id := id,
@projectId := project_id
FROM tmp1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @i := 0, @id := '', @sum := 0) AS InitVarsAlias;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any possibility of null here, when you are tying to add aantal to the mix?

Comment: No, aantal does always have a value

Comment: I solved it by running this query and store it in a dummy mem table before running in and store it in tmp2. So the query will always run twice. Of course this is not a good solution but solves my problem for now.